# USB Selective Suspend causes keyboard to miss keys and USB hubs, eGPU, and docs to disconnect

Tags: windows, usb, keyboard, windows-11, usb-hub

I've read post from quite a few furiously frustrated individuals plagued by the same issue without a resolution.

There were several things I observed going wrong on my fresh install of Windows 11 with updated drivers.

1. USB devices connected to my eGPU (Razer Core X Chroma) USB ports would cut out, but ethernet was fine.
2. USB devices connected to my Thunderbolt 3 hub USB ports would cut out, but monitors were fine.
3. My USB keyboard would ignore the first keystroke after a few minutes of inactivity, and sometimes only a few seconds.
4. Rarely, My USB keyboard would lag and then completely cut out and not recover until plugged in to a new port.
5. The USB hub built into my dell monitor (daisy chained to the eGPU dock via USB) was also unstable.

I saw it recommended to disable USB Selective Suspend in the Advanced Power Plan settings, but on my Microsoft Surface Laptop Studio, that option doesn't appear by default.  I tried running scripts to edit the registry and force power options to show up, but toggling them didn't help.  Also, I don't actually want that feature disabled, I'd rather have it work correctly since it saves power and USB bus resources.

I did, however, learn that the USB Sleep timeout is set to 50 milliseconds which may have something to do with why devices like the keyboard cut out even while in active use.

Further, I found an article on Microsoft's site that mentioned USB devices can end up frozen in a bad state if they receive a suspend request, but then are asked to wake up again before fully suspended which matches the behavior I'm seeing with the keyboard.  So I think we're on the right track with USB sleep behavior being the source of the problem.

Comment: You can get to the advanced power options and potentially disable USB Selective Suspend by temporarily disabling Connected Standby https://surfacetip.com/how-to-unlock-power-plans-on-surface-devices/  apparently the settings you change should remain after re-enabling Connected Standby.

Comment: @Mokubai , that's a super helpful tip.  I was not aware of the Connected Standby feature and it hiding advanced power options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several days of trial and error I finally landed on a solution that seems to be consistently stable.

Rather than disable USB selective suspend system-wide, you need to tell Windows which USB devices it should not attempt to turn off to save power.

### Prevent Each USB Input Device from Suspending

1. Head to the **Device Manager** (<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> -> Device Manager, or search for it in the Start Menu).
2. Expand the list for **Human Interface Devices** (Depending on what is cutting out, the Bluetooth and Universal Serial Bus Controllers may be relevant too).

There may be quite a few things listed for your system, mine has lots of entries for touch screen, pen, etc, but what you're looking for is either the name of your device or **"USB Input Device."**

3. For each of those, right-click on the name and choose **Properties**, then go to the **Power Management tab**. (If there is no Power Management tab, just skip that one.)
4. **Deselect** "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power".

[image: USB Input Device Property Power Management Settings]

Note: When you plug a device into a different USB port, you may need to follow these steps again to switch it back off.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but with logitech mouse over bluetooth.
Also running windows 11, no issues on previous windows.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1129758)

Comment: Sorry to hear you're having trouble too.  As MiG mentioned, this probably makes more sense as a comment on the other answer rather than as a separate answer.  Just trying to keep you from getting downvoted. :-)